# Mean Stack - Package services

Tags: express, mean-stack

I've taken over a full built application using the MEAN stack.  The one thing I'm noticing is the controllers are just huge, a ton of logic in them, repetitive code, private functions, etc.   Normally I would think much of this would go into a service class for the individual packages within the application, but I can't find anything in the documentation or via online searches for structures such as this.

Current structure is something like

foo/
--server/
 
----controllers/
 
----docs/
----routes/
----tests/
----views/

What I'm used to is a structure like above but with a services directory under the server directory as well.  Instead of having so much logic in the controller, it would live in the service instead.

Anything wrong with this approach?   Is there a better way to go about it? Or is it just accepted that with this framework that the majority of the logic lives in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with this approach. A lot of the time reusable components end up living in a modules folder in server. The main thing is Express is not opinionated about the structure of your files. Some generators offer opinions about where files live and that looks like the case in your example, but because they are just generators you can extend and change their structure so long as all of your require statements are valid.